# Creating an online appointment scheduler

Tags: open-source

I would like to create an online appointment scheduler.

Here are some of the key features on the client (web) side

1. Create and manage schedule for various people/other assets on the team.
2. Full calendar visualization - like Microsoft Outlook Calendar. E.g., should be able to add an appointment for "John" from 2 to 3 PM on December 5th
3. Color coding

For server-side, I should be able to store/extract the appointments for each asset for a date/time

Can you please suggest the optimal technology stack for both the web-side and server side programming.